# What to do when a comment is added as an answer in "First Post" or/and "Late Answer"?

Tags: discussion, review, new-users, late-answers, comments-as-answers

While reviewing I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752916/oracle-daily-db-backup-without-enterprise-manager/17965970#17965970) post. It was actually my *Late Answer* post review, but it is not only a Late Answer review but also a First Post review for the same post since the reputation of user was 1. Because of reputation limit the user can't comment hence he made comment in answer box. My point is should there be a feature where a new user wants to do which activity first like 'Asking a Question' or 'Answer' or 'Comment'. if I downvote it then the new user feels uncomfortable with site. If his/her post is flagged because of our rule then this is also not good, because he/she may have some better solution, but reputation limit and rules of answer is restricting him/her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What to do when “First Post” or/and “Late Answer” is comment as Answer?

You can (in order to priority - IMHO)

- flag the post as "not an answer".
- comment on that post and explain the poster about how comments and answers work
- downvote.

Mostly, when I see such posts from new users I flag the post, then add a comment something like this:

> Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have a look at our [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page. To critique or request clarification from an author, [leave a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) below their post.